# JSF - Getting NullPointerException in constructor when accessing getFacade()

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

this code produces NullPointerException. I don't know why. When I put the code from constructor to some other void with @PostConstruct - it works. I tried to initiate klientFacade - but it's not working, either. The class KlientFacade is @Stateless.

```
package view;
import entity.Klient;
import facade.KlientFacade;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import static util.Messages.addFlashMessage;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ManageClient implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private KlientFacade klientFacade;
    private List<Klient> clientList;

    public List<Klient> returnClientList(){
        return getKlientFacade().findAll();
    }

    public ManageClient() {
        clientList = new ArrayList<>();
        clientList = returnClientList();
    }

    public String removeClient(Klient klient){
        addFlashMessage("Klient ["+klient.getLogin()+"] został usunięty.");
        getKlientFacade().remove(klient);
        return "manage";
    }

    public List<Klient> getClientList() {
        return clientList;
    }

    public void setClientList(List<Klient> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
    }

    public KlientFacade getKlientFacade() {
        return klientFacade;
    }

    public void setKlientFacade(KlientFacade klientFacade) {
        this.klientFacade = klientFacade;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `klientFacade`. NPE's are the easiest of exceptions: just use your debugger, step trough the code and look for a `null` value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant access property of managed bean from another managed bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048682/cant-access-property-of-managed-bean-from-another-managed-bean/17048774#17048774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its because injected objects are not instantiated before the constructor call. Thats why you are not getting NPE with `@PostConstruct` annotation. If you still need to access injected fields in constructor, try http://openejb.apache.org/constructor-injection.html.

Comment: I am still getting null in my facade EJB